# Merge/Concatenate two dictionaries (/tuples) with same keys python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two json objects represented as a dictionary and I want to concatenate both into one and the last will be a json.

At the moment I have:

```
obj1 = {
    "FS":11440000,
    "BW":76000000,
    "Gain":62,
    "Fc":70000000,
    "real":[ 4,2,3,],
    "imag":[1,1,3,],
}

obj2 = {
    "FS":61440000,
    "BW":56000000,
    "Gain":62,
    "Fc":80000000,
    "real":[ 1,2,3,],
    "imag":[1,2,3,],
}
```

I want  to have:

```
[
    {
    [
        {
           "FS":61440000,
           "BW":56000000,
           "Gain":62,
           "Fc":70000000,
           "real":[ 1,2,3,],
           "imag":[1,2,3,],
        },
        {
           "FS":61440000,
           "BW":56000000,
           "N":8192,
           "Gain":62,
           "Fc":80000000,
           "real":[ 1,2,3,],
           "imag":[1,2,3,],
        }   
    ],
    "ts":1231234165234,
    "scale":[10000,-45],
    "N":8192,
    },

]
```

How to join `obj1` + `obj2` and remain the keys and not update them? I need all of them as you can see the final output I'm trying to create.

After concatenating `obj1` and `obj2` into one I need to add 3 more keys.

I'm using python 3.6.

Comment: where did the `"ts"`, `"scale"` and `"N"` came from? You are not concatenating dictionaries here, you are just placing them in a list

Comment: I tried merge and now the only thing working is data=((obj1),(obj2)) but after i cant add new key value to the new tuple

Comment: ts scale and N are keys i need to add at the end of  the json.

Answer (score 1):

The dict output you expect is badly formatted, so you will never be able to make it. (dicts needs **key** for each value - even if value can be list).

```
foo = {"foo": "value"}
bar = {"bar": "value"}
data = {"ts": "...", "scale": [10000, -45], "N": 8192, "data": [foo, bar]}
```

Would gives you a dict where you can access data via `data['data']`

Comment: I dont wan´t "data", i want foo, bar, ts, scale and N

Comment: Great, but you can not. At least provide a **correct output** you expect to have.

Comment: @ricardol Indeed, it is not possible. When inserting into a dict, keys are a must.

Comment: At he moment i have a tuple with obj1 and obj2. After thsi i want to add 3 new key/value

Comment: @ricardol you have to **learn and understand**, else you will maybe find a solution, but if you don't understand how dicts works, you will never be able to do anything efficient, really, it's a friendly advise.